# Is there a way to display (enemy) champion basic information while in a match?

Tags: league-of-legends

Because I am still relatively new to League of Legends I don't know all the champions names and their abilities only by their portrait. Because I mostly play normal matches where champions are picked *blindly* I have no chance to click on the enemy portraits and gain that information before the game starts.
Is there any way to display this information (name, type, abilities) while being already **in** a match? Or do I have to look it up on some website, given that I can identify the champions name by its portrait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to see the skills of enemies altough not all i think (It's been a while since i checked it). If you die and you click on death information (seeing wich enemy killed you and such) You will see what skills did damage to you and some information, also it will show you some tips about the enemy.

Types will not be shown.

**Update:** So If you die you have the death recap, you can click on enemy champions and see some tips. The same as the champion screens i think. And then you can hover over some of the skills that did damage to you and get some info about them. But thats all tho.

Comment: So you say, other than letting me kill by them, there's no chance to get information about their skills? Too sad :/

Comment: @F.S. Yep thats about it, but if you want to know more about the champions i suggest you check out the champion spotlights. There are alot of them at the moment altough not all are new, but mostly the skills stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

In game, the only way is for the enemy champion to get a kill/assist on you.  Then, you can review the damage and see what their abilities do.

If you have a smartphone, I'd recommend checking out some of the LoL apps.  They neatly solve this problem without pulling too much attention away from the game.

Comment: 2nd monitor + wikia > smartphone :) Still both useless until I know at least the name of the champion

Comment: The champion name is listed on the loading screen, and if you press `tab` during play.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry i made a mistake here answered the wrong question, so as far as viewing champion information while in game there is technically Only one way and that is

- by getting killed by that champion or group of champions you are
  given a small amount of information about that champion and the
  skills you should avoid and basic information for laning against said
  champions maximum of three you need to hover over their abilities
  though

Now using a browser is more or less the absolute best way however doing this while in game is not particularly smart, so what you can do is use this application.  www.overwolf.com. It has a host of different features and such things for different games however you want the browser now its all in game so while your game is loading

- you may simply just click on the over wolf icon go to more apps and
  select browser.

The Overwolf application is a very light weight overlay applcation with a lot of useful apps for games I recently found this while looking for lol timers.

The websites you want to go to are championselect.net and lolcounter.com. these will give you information on any champion you want. Do this often enough and play long enough and you will not need to use a browser I personally never do anymore so I suppose one another answer to you're question is practice!!!